# ¿Cómo puedo agrupar objetos con keys creando una nueva matriz? JS

Tags: javascript

Necesito crear una matriz partiendo de otra pero agregando un nombre de key e insertarles los objetos que tengan el mismo `svr_name` para tener orden y agruparlos.

Uso la query mongodb atlas/mongoose find() y traigo todos los documentos creados. Por ese motivo los documentos pueden tener valores diferentes en su propiedad `svr_name`.

Obtengo esto:
Dejo solo la propiedad `svr_name` para ahorrar espacio y se entienda mejor

```
 const arr = [
        {
        "message": [
          {"svr_name": "mazda"//otras propiedades},
          {"svr_name": "suzuki"//...},
          {"svr_name": "roadmaster"},
          {"svr_name": "suzuki"},
          {"svr_name": "mazda"}
        ]
      }
    ]
```

Y necesito algo como esto:

```
const newArr = [{
    "message": [{
        mazda:[
            { "svr_name": "mazda"},
            { "svr_name": "mazda"}
            //....
        ],
        suzuki:[
            { "svr_name": "suzuki"},
            { "svr_name": "suzuki"}
            //....
        ],
        roadmaster:[
            { "svr_name": "roadmaster"},
            { "svr_name": "roadmaster"}
            //....
        ],
    }]
}]
```

En mi lógica, intento extraer todos los valores únicos de los documentos en su propiedad name y esto me dice que "nombres(svr_name)" tengo en todos los documentos:

```
const svr= [...new Set(arr.flatMap(msg=>[...msg.message].map(name=> name.svr_name)))]
```

Luego intento crear el nuevo array con el length de `svr` (lo svr_name existentes) pero no logro entender como crear las keys  e insertarles solo los objetos iguales.

```
//Solo es algo que intento hacer pero no llego a nada
const svr_names = [...new Array(svr.length)].flatMap(s=> arr.map(t=>[...t.message].map(m=> m.svr_name)))
```

Agradezco la ayuda, muchas gracias.

Comment: hay varias formas de resolverlo, pero me gustaria saber como averigüas donde colocar cada elemento dentro de `carros`, `bicicletas` y `motos` para elavorar una respuesta decente

Comment: Me surge la misma duda que ha @AngelCordones, entiendo que quieres agrupar por las `keys`,  pero ¿como sabes a que `Array` o grupo va cada uno?

Comment: @AngelCordones  @Josbert Edito la pregunta. Tienen toda la razón, cometí el error al crear la pregunta.  Los keys carros. bic... deben ser los values de la propiedad svr_names, ya que el motivo por el que cree la const `svr` es para saber los valores únicos de esta propiedad y con esto crear los keys e insertarles los objetos que tengan el value de svr_names igual, tal como esta en `newArray`. Gracias, espero puedan ayudarme

Comment: Perfecto, ya te entiendo mejor jaja, es muy interesante. Hay una manera de hacer esto pero no recuerdo bien. Echare un poco de cabeza aquí :D

Comment: @Josbert Muchas gracias :)

Comment: Okey encontré la solución..!! ya la coloco como respuesta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bien, tenia recuerdos de un método mas primitivo *programaticamente* hablando para esto, que consistía en unos cuantos bucles `for`, pero no logre recordarla. Sin embargo encontré una solución a esto y va perfecto..!!

**La solución es la siguiente:**

```js
/** 
 * Esta es la función
 */
function groupBy(element){

  // Creamos un objeto vació de salida
  let output = {}
  
  // Recorremos el Array original
  element.forEach( item => {
    
    // Si no existe la propiedad, la creamos con valor de un Array vacio
    if(!output.hasOwnProperty(item.svr_name)){
      Object.defineProperty(output, item.svr_name, {
        value: [],
        writable: true,
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true
      })
    }
    
    // Añadimos el item actual a la propiedad con su mismo nombre
    output[item.svr_name].push(item)
    
  })
  
  // Retornamos el objecto de salida
  return output

}

/** 
 * Acá la testamos
 */
let array = [
  {
    "message": [
      {"svr_name": "mazda"},
      {"svr_name": "suzuki"},
      {"svr_name": "roadmaster"},
      {"svr_name": "suzuki"},
      {"svr_name": "mazda"}
    ]
  }
]

// Imprimimos su salida
let testing = groupBy(array[0].message)
console.log(testing)
```

Gracias a el método estático [Object.defineProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) de **Javascript** esto se nos facilita mucho, también puedes ver que estamos comprobando existencia de una propiedad con el método [Object.hasOwnProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty).

###### Bonus:

Investigando un poco, supe que en el método `Object.defineProperty()`
mencionado antes, se pueden establecer **getters** y **setters**, de
hecho es lo que usan librerias como **Vue.js** para ofrecer
reactividad en sus propiedades :D

Comment: Es la respuesta exacta a mi pregunta. Muchísimas gracias por su tiempo @Josbert

Comment: Con todo gusto amigo..!! muy interesante tu problema de verdad :)